# Iterate boxplot R model.frame.default

Tags: r, loops, boxplot

I have a question regarding looping a data frame and making a boxplot of each numerical column of the data frame dependent on another data frame. For example, from mtcars: providing a boxplot of each column vs. the gear column.

I tried something like the following:

```
for (i in names(mtcars)){
boxplot(i ~ gear, data = mtcars)
}
```

This, however, results in the following error:

```
 "Error in model.frame.default(formula = i ~ gear, data = mtcars) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'gear')"
```

I know that there are other posts on StackOverflow that show that in some cases NA values prohibit this kind of formula from working, but the mtcars dataset is a complete dataset, so NA values cannot be an issue.

My question: how can I easily create a boxplot for each variable vs. a 'fixed' variable from a data frame? For example:

```
boxplot(mpg ~ gear, data = mtcars)

boxplot(cyl ~ gear, data = mtcars)
```

And so on.

Other posts relating to this error in another context can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=model.frame.default%20boxplot).

Unfortunately I was not able to solve my problem with the answers described here, because in most cases NA values were a problem, or something more technical as extracting elements from a list when using a user-defined function.

Comment: Change `boxplot(i ~ gear, data = mtcars)` to `boxplot(reformulate(i, "gear"), data = mtcars)` and your for loop will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `get` before `i` in your for loop.
From your question it is not clear what the output should be. If I may continue from your for `loop`, you can do this:

```
for(i in names(mtcars)){
with(mtcars, boxplot(get(i) ~ gear))
}
```